# Usage of the abbreviation of a specific-type short phrase

Tags: word-usage

Could you tell me how to abbreviate few-word phrases as in the use of "mobile" for "the mobile business" in the sentence

> "Company A's lagging position in mobile is the most pressing challenge?"

When I come across such an abbreviation, I wonder why it should be "mobile," but not "mobiles" nor "the mobile" (shorthand for the mobile *business*).

I would like to know the rationale behind this particular type of abbreviation.

Comment: Abbreviations like that rarely follow rationales. They tend to be spurious and somewhat random. ‘Mobile’ in your example actually seems quite strange and unnatural to me—I would have used ‘the mobile market’ if I were writing the phrase myself.

Answer (score 2):

It is common in business to refer to a field or sector by the adjective that describes that category of enterprise, such as *Kodak suffered when it continued to focus on **chemical** and ignored **digital** until it was too late.*

In these cases, the adjective is used as a noun and a term such as *field, sector* or *area* is understood.

Even the term *mobiles* is really just a plural version of the adjective *mobile* that has been transformed to a noun to represent *mobile telephone*.

Comment: Thank you so much! How about "electronics?" As far as I know, it is always used in the plural when used as a noun. In the case of your example sentence, it it also possible to use "focus on chemicalS?"

Comment: Yes. While adjectives can be used in place of nouns, nouns can also be used as adjectives. *Kodak focuses on the **chemicals** sector*.